# Correct way to store samples in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a matrix (two-dimensional numpy array) storing multivariate sample data. Is it correct (wrt speed and ease of use) to store the data using one **row** for each sample or one **column** for each? E.g

```
array([[x1, y1, ...], [x2, y2, ...], ..., [xN, yN, ...]])
```

or

```
array([[x1, x2, ..., xN], [y1, y2, ..., yN], ...])
```

In MATLAB and Octave, it is definitely easier to treat each sample as a **column** vector, but numpy gives you no indication either way.

For example. Here is how you can normalize a set of samples if each one is stored as a row vector:

```
X - mean(X, axis = 0)
```

But if you store them as column vectors you have to write

```
(X.T - mean(X, axis = 1)).T
```

Which absolutely is not as convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The performance depends on both the access pattern and the memory layout of the array. The latter may be set with the [`order` parameter of `np.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), which:

> Specify the memory layout of the array. If object is not an array, the newly created array will be in C order (row major) unless ‘F’ is specified, in which case it will be in Fortran order (column major).

(If object is an array, there are more options as the layout may be preserved.)

Also the right approach may depend on the libraries you depend on. For example for [linear regression in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) you are expected to have one row for each sample.

[EDIT]

Storing samples in rows is also compatible with `pandas.DataFrame` objects:

```
>>> CIRCLES = np.array([[1, 3.14],
...                     [2, 12.56],
...                     [3, 28.26]])
>>> DF = DataFrame(CIRCLES, columns=['r', 'S'])
>>> DF.mean()
r     2.000000
S    14.653333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19558207)

Comment: @ahajib agreed.

Comment: I didn't think to look at how external libraries do it. But if these scikit libraries are strong samples a row vectors, then that must be the right way to do it?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I'd rather say it is "a compatible way".